# icons in the graph view not presisting

Tags: orientdb

I am using OrientDB 2.2, when I go into the graph view and set icons and display template and then save it, later on when I log back into the server and view the graph the icons and display template are revered back to the default view.

Is this a bug? is there a fix for it or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't doing anything wrong, yes it's a known issue, try with a database user like `admin`